# Cannot insert textbox data into Access error:0x80040e57

Tags: c#, insert

I have tried to insert data into my database but I find there is a strange error: the error message is: 0x80040e57
A literal value in the command overflowed the range of the type of the associated column.

Here is my code

```
  private void btn_insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
               + "Data Source=DB.accdb");

            connection.Open();
        string insert = "INSERT INTO membership(member_id,member_name,member_password,gender,dob,member_lv,email,tel_no)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(insert, connection);
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("member_id", memid_txt.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("member_name", memname_txt.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("member_password", mempass_txt.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("gender", memgender_txt.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("dob", memdob_txt.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("member_lv", memlv_txt.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", mememail_txt.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("tel_no", telno.Text);

        try
        {


             cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Insert Successful Please Click The Load Table Button To See The Newest Update!!!");
            connection.Close();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }
    }
```

I want to insert following data into the access:

```
member_id : M0003

member_name: member01    
member_password: 12345678    
gender : male    
dob : 2015/10/10    
member_lv : gold    
tel_no : 23456789
```

I checked my access twice. I ensured all the columns have 255 chars except dob (I set dob as date/time).

It is so strange that the error message telling me my data is out of the range. Can somebody tell me where is the problem?

The error message is

> Database error 0x80040E57: The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Try inserting or pasting less data"

Comment: Can you share the full Exception message here

Comment: The error message is Database error 0x80040E57: The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Try inserting or pasting less data"

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You set dob as a DateTime but you pass a string.....and everything breaks. How do you expect that string to be converted to a Date? What is the convention used to convert it? In other words,  Stop using AddWithValue and use an appropriate constructor for you parameter, one in which you could specify the OleDbType

Comment: Just guessing here, the DOB needs to be cast to a DateTime.

Comment: then how should I insert date into the database?

Comment: First you need to convert your string to a Date (IE DateTime.TryParse) then you could add the parameters with _cmd2.Parameters.Add("dob", OleDbType.Date).Value = _converted_value_of_memdob_txt;_

Comment: I added DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(memdob_txt.Text); and changed cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("dob", memdob_txt.Text); to cmd2.Parameters.Add("dob", OleDbType.Date).Value = dt; but it still doesnt work